# how many line segments can be drawn that connect the point to the line so that the segment and the line are perpendicular in 3-space?

Tags: geometry, 3d

Given a line and a point not on the line, how many line segments can be drawn that connect the point to the line so that the segment and the line are perpendicular in 2-space? In 3-space?

In 2-space, it would have to be a 1 unique line segment. Is it the same in 3-space?

Comment: Yes. You could probably convince yourself intuitively if you can visualize the situation

Comment: Is there a way to show it visually in 3-space?

Answer (score 0):

Note that any line segment that goes through a line and a point not on the line, must be in the plane defined by the line and the point. Hence, we can reduce the problem down to 2 dimensions in that plane, in which case the aforementioned theorem holds.